# Filtering an array using lambda not working as expected

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to filter a string array using the following code

```
        String[] temp = { "apple", "Orange", "avocado" };
        var newtemp = temp.Where(x => x.IndexOf("apple") != -1);
```

I am hoping that variable newtemp will only contain "apple" but that is not happening, it contains all three strings after the second line is executed. How can I achieve what I want to do.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It works fine for me. (Noting, though, that `Where` is lazy-evaluated, so `newtemp` doesn't *really* contain any elements, it just provides an iterator that incorporates your predicate...) Note also `x.Contains("apple")` would be a lot more readable and is equivalent.

Comment: Works fine for me too, maybe post the rest of the code that shows all three elements in newtemp variable.

Comment: Perfect dvnrrs Now I understand whats happening. While debugging I was hovering over newtemp and then expanding "non public members" and then I saw that there are 3 elements but now I noticed that when I loop through newtemp it only loops for one element. Thanks.

Comment: @nikhilkoganti:  note that `x.Contains("apple")` does the same but is more readable if you don't actually need the index.

Comment: Noted Tim Schmelter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ToList() to force execution.

var newtemp = temp.Where(x => x.IndexOf("apple") != -1).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

If you use First it will get you a single string if one exists.

```
        String[] temp = { "apple", "Orange", "avocado" };
        var newTemp = temp.First(x => x.IndexOf("apple") != -1);
```